# What´s the easiest to extract data from a series of Webpages?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, extract, data-extraction

Here is my problem:

I have the sitemap.xlm from an e-commerce. It contains all the URL for its products. From those URL I want to get the name of the product (and maybe its price). My first idea was using Google App Script:

```
function test() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.leroymerlin.com.br/emenda-rigido-de-pvc-600cm-plasbil_87821293");

  Logger.log(response);

  var ind;

   while( ind = /<img src="([^"]*)/.exec( response.getContentText()) ){ 
     Logger.log(ind[1]);
   }

}
```

Whoever the UrlFetchApp.fetch() method is not reliable at all. So I soon realize that this is not my best option.

This is a very simple task. I don´t want by any means build something that craws the whole site. I just want to extract some data from a set of URLs. So I figure there must be a simple solution. Unfortunately, everything I found doing a GoolgeSearch was either too complicated (a crawler that goes through the whole site) or it wasn´t free.

I need a javascript based solution. I would also be great if it was a webbased solution (something that I can do on my browser), but if I have to use a program it would also be OK. Or even a solution to make this work on Google App Script would work for me.

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: What makes you think that a scraper would be simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) a try. It's basically a webkit based browser without any visible window. The API is nativey in JS and rather easy. You can even use CSS selectors to get specific parts of the page in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser's [DOM parser](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/) and [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp) for loading a URL and parsing it (repeat for each url):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// create your DOM element
var myPage = document.createElement('html');
// now load myPage with the html from url
loadURLHtml("http://myURL");

function loadURLHtml(url)
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      // POPULATE HTML into your DOM
      myPage.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      if (myPage.innerHTML)
      {
        // get your element of interest from the loaded html in the DOM
        myPage.getElementsByTagName('myTag'); 
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```